# Sending picture in Whatsapp using html or jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, whatsapp

I want to share a image using WhatsApp.
I try with this code but I only share the url:

```
<div id='whatsapp'>
<a data-action='share/whatsapp/share' expr:href='&quot;whatsapp://send?text=&quot; + data:post.title + &quot;-&quot; + data:post.url' title='Compartir en WhatsApp' alt='Compartir en WhatsApp'>
text
</a>
</div>

<p>Test <a href="whatsapp://send?text=Probando%20a%20compartir%20en%20Whatsapp%20con%20el%20método%20que%20explica%20el%20blog%20de%20Antonio%20Rull:%20http://antoniorull.com/2015/04/04/anade-un-boton-para-compartir-en-whatsapp/?utm_source=m%C3%B3vil&amp;utm_medium=whatsapp&amp;utm_campaign=whatsapp" target="_blank">Link</a>.</p>

https://jsfiddle.net/xy9o6u83
```

How can I add the url of the image to send it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Whatsapp have any public API (for now) so I am not sure if you can do that.